# How do I get a single row value in a group statement?

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g

I have two tables, `JobTable` and `EmployeeTable` with the following data:

EmployeeTable:

```
EmpId    Salary
1          10
2          20
3          30
4          40
5          50
6          60
```

JobTable:

```
JobId    EmpId
A          1
A          2
B          3 
B          4
C          5
C          6
```

I need an SQL statement that will return the `EmpId` of the Employee with the minimum salary for each Job.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `RANK()` function like this:

```
WITH ranked AS (
  SELECT
    j.JobId,
    e.EmpId,
    e.Salary,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY j.JobId ORDER BY e.Salary) AS rnk
  FROM JobTable j
  INNER JOIN EmployeeTable e ON j.EmpId = e.EmpId
)
SELECT
  JobId,
  EmpId,
  Salary,
FROM ranked
WHERE rnk = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, give this one a shot:

```
SELECT st.EmpID, min(st.salary) 
FROM SalaryTable st INNER JOIN JobTable jt ON st.EmpID=jt.EmpID 
WHERE jt.JobID = 'A' 
GROUP BY st.EmpID
```